# Rename jQuery UI tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to rename this every tabs, with different names.
Its showing tab 1, tab 2.... etc.

```
$(function() {
    var total_tabs = 0;

    // initialize first tab
    total_tabs++;
    addtab(total_tabs);

    $("#addtab, #litab").click(function() {
        total_tabs++;
        $("#tabcontent p").hide();
        addtab(total_tabs);
        return false;
    });

    function addtab(count) {
        var closetab = '<a href="" id="close'+count+'" class="close">&times;</a>';
        $("#tabul").append('<li id="t'+count+'" class="ntabs">Tab '+count+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+closetab+'</li>');
        $("#tabcontent").append('<p id="c'+count+'">Tab Content '+count+'</p>');

        $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");
        $("#t"+count).addClass("ctab");

        $("#t"+count).bind("click", function() {
            $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");
            $("#t"+count).addClass("ctab");
            $("#tabcontent p").hide();
            $("#c"+count).fadeIn('slow');
        });

        $("#close"+count).bind("click", function() {
            // activate the previous tab
            $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");
            $("#tabcontent p").hide();
            $(this).parent().prev().addClass("ctab");
            $("#c"+count).prev().fadeIn('slow');

            $(this).parent().remove();
            $("#c"+count).remove();
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

how can i add rename function for every tabs i create.
can i use popup box to rename tabs?

I want to rename this with GUI system,Like below link.

http://demo.superdit.com/jquery/dynamic_tab.html

i want to rename it on there.( by using popup box or something)

Thanks you...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function addtab(count, tabName) {
    var closetab = '<a href="" id="close'+count+'" class="close">&times;</a>';
    $("#tabul").append('<li id="t'+count+'" class="ntabs">'+tabName+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+closetab+'</li>');
    $("#tabcontent").append('<p id="c'+count+'">Tab Content '+count+'</p>');

    $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");
    $("#t"+count).addClass("ctab");

    $("#t"+count).bind("click", function() {
        $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");
        $("#t"+count).addClass("ctab");
        $("#tabcontent p").hide();
        $("#c"+count).fadeIn('slow');
    });

    $("#close"+count).bind("click", function() {
        // activate the previous tab
        $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");
        $("#tabcontent p").hide();
        $(this).parent().prev().addClass("ctab");
        $("#c"+count).prev().fadeIn('slow');

        $(this).parent().remove();
        $("#c"+count).remove();
        return false;
    });
}
});
```

It's your function, with only two changes.
First, I added an extra parameter to the function, `tabName`, representing the name of the tab.

```
function addtab(count, tabName)
```

This means you will now call the function like this `addTab(1, "Awesome tab name")`

Second, I changed this line

```
 $("#tabul").append('<li id="t'+count+'" class="ntabs">Tab '+count+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+closetab+'</li>');
```

to

```
 $("#tabul").append('<li id="t'+count+'" class="ntabs">Tab '+count+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+closetab+'</li>');
```

Originally, the tab name was set as *Tab 1* where 1 was the value of the `count` parameter ( `Tab '+count+'` ). Now, the tab name will the name you give it when you call the function.

[**edit**]
For the tab renaming, you could try this version:

```
function addtab(count, tabName) {
    var closetab = '<a href="" id="close'+count+'" class="close">&times;</a>';
    $("#tabul").append('<li id="t'+count+'" class="ntabs"><span id="title' + count + '">'+tabName+'</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;'+closetab+'</li>');
    $("#tabcontent").append('<p id="c'+count+'">Tab Content '+count+'</p>');

    $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");
    $("#t"+count).addClass("ctab");

    $("#t"+count).bind("click", function() {
        $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");
        $("#t"+count).addClass("ctab");
        $("#tabcontent p").hide();
        $("#c"+count).fadeIn('slow');
    });

    $("#span"+count).bind("click", function() {
        var newTitle = prompt("Enter the new title","");
        if (newTitle && newTitle !== "") {
            $(this).innerText = newTitle;
        }
    });


    $("#close"+count).bind("click", function() {
        // activate the previous tab
        $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");
        $("#tabcontent p").hide();
        $(this).parent().prev().addClass("ctab");
        $("#c"+count).prev().fadeIn('slow');

        $(this).parent().remove();
        $("#c"+count).remove();
        return false;
    });
}
});
```

First, I placed the tab title in a separate element, a `span`
`$("#tabul").append('<li id="t'+count+'" class="ntabs"><span id="title' + count + '">'+tabName+'</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;'+closetab+'</li>');`

Then I made the title to display a javascript prompt box asking you for a title and setting the text of the span as the given value

```
$("#span"+count).bind("click", function() {
        var newTitle = prompt("Enter the new title","");
        if (newTitle && newTitle !== "") {
            $(this).innerText = newTitle;
        }
    });
```

I'm not sure it will work 100% since I'm not a jQuery user, but it should give you a basic idea on how it's done

Comment: Every tab names different with each one.It mean all tabs allow to change  their name after created the tabs.
is it possible?

Comment: Let me see if I got this right, do you want to be able to edit the names of the tabs after you created them?

Comment: yes . like that.
want to replace it with new names in interface.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I'll try to add some code when I'll have time